# how can i got n element of json file using script shell

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have this json file historique.json. It created by script bash , i call the script in Jenkinsfile.

```
[
  {
    "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
    "PTF_CONTENT": [
      {
        "NAME": "api_batch_API",
        "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
        "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14",
        "CONFIG_FILE": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 10:12:10",
    "PTF_CONTENT": [
      {
        "NAME": "api_back_API",
        "CHECKED": "api_back_NOT_SELECTED",
        "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14",
        "CONFIG_FILE": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So when I do a build in jenkins an element has added in the last of file historique.json like below:

```
[
      {
        "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
        "PTF_CONTENT": [
          {
            "NAME": "api_batch_API",
            "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
            "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14",
            "CONFIG_FILE": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 10:12:10",
        "PTF_CONTENT": [
          {
            "NAME": "api_back_API",
            "CHECKED": "api_back_NOT_SELECTED",
            "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14",
            "CONFIG_FILE": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 11:12:10",
        "PTF_CONTENT": [
          {
            "NAME": "api_ihm_API",
            "CHECKED": "api_ihm_NOT_SELECTED",
            "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14",
            "CONFIG_FILE": ""
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
```

And ect.(In my case now I have many element in the json file). 
So my question is how I can get just the last 15 element and the rest deleted?
I try this but doesn't work for me :

```
for k in $(jq length historique.json); do
if [[ $k -gt 15 ]]; then
jq 'del(.[0])' historique.json > historique1.json
fi
done
```

Any suggestion ??(And sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I am understanding you correctly, you can use the jq range operator:

```
jq '.[-15:]' historique.json
```

This should return the last 15 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To output just the last 15 elements of an array, use slice syntax.

```
jq '.[-15:]' historique.json
```